# Why is alert($('.myClass').hasClass('myClass')); false?

Tags: jquery

When the page loads i replace the attributes of a specific object. Then in a few lines under(maybe directly under) i do another check which always seems to fail. So i tried

```
alert($('.myClass').hasClass('myClass'));
```

and by all logic shouldnt that always return true?
I set a breakpoint in firebug and i can see the object with the new attribute however... why does this line fail?

Comment: works just perfect, can you provide a link or something?

Comment: It works: http://www.jsfiddle.net/JSc5n/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*by all logic shouldnt that always return true?*
It will return `false` if your selector matches no elements. Are you sure that's not the case? You can try this to check:

```
alert($('.myClass').length);
```

Comment: ah! typo in the class name. I had to shuffle lines and write new code and i didnt know which part broke. Accept when the site allows

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
var myclasses = $('.myClass');

alert(!myclasses.length || myclasses.hasClass('myClass'));
```

Comment: Thats a funny way of telling me i am matching no elements :p +1 anyways

Comment: Your code is the same as what OP has now for all practical purposes. Maybe want `||` instead of `&&`, I'm not sure.

Comment: Oops. I meant: `!myclasses.length || myclasses.hasClass('myClass')` It's 3am :)